# Printing barcode from web browser

Tags: css, barcode

I have trouble printing barcodes from browser for one web application that I'm developing.

I found many libraries that can do the barcodes for me. Some libraries show the barcode as image some in CSS.

The print quality is OK. My problem is that the starting point / the margins are too much and one of the labels that I suppose to print is small and there is too much white space and too little left for printing.

I tried to control printing area with CSS but it didn't work.

Any suggestions on solution regarding this issue are highly appreciated!

Comment: what code are you trying to print out from your web application? 39, 128, Ean, Upc?

Answer (score 0):

Your standard 3 of 9 barcode is simply a font.  You can't rely on a font to be installed on any local machine.  Are your libraries rendering the barcodes as an image file such as png's?